# Assign a list of values to a scaleable custom list of objects

Tags: c#, loops, variable-assignment

Below is an example for the largest set of objects that could be found in my list which is generated elsewhere. There could potentially be less groups or a lower number of values in each group.

```
CustomObject COOLING_111; //Start of Cooling group 1 - section 1
CustomObject COOLING_112;
CustomObject COOLING_113;
CustomObject COOLING_114;
CustomObject COOLING_115;
CustomObject COOLING_116;
CustomObject COOLING_117;
CustomObject COOLING_118;


CustomObject COOLING_121; //Start of Cooling group 1 - section 2
...
CustomObject COOLING_128


CustomObject COOLING_211; //Start of Cooling group 2 - section 1
...
CustomObject COOLING_218;


CustomObject COOLING_221; //Start of Cooling group 2 - section 2
...
CustomObject COOLING_228;


CustomObject COOLING_311; //Start of Cooling group 3 - section 1
...
CustomObject COOLING_318;


CustomObject COOLING_321; //Start of Cooling group 3 - section 2
...
CustomObject COOLING_328;


CustomObject COOLING_411; //Start of Cooling group 4 - section 1
...
CustomObject COOLING_418;


CustomObject COOLING_421; //Start of Cooling group 4 - section 2
...
CustomObject  COOLING_428;
```

---

***How can I edit / create a loop or sequence of conditional statements so that the variables from my array are specifically assigned in the order described by the example:***

- set every object's value to -1.
- set the value of any number of objects (for instance the first 6) in the following pattern:

  - the first object from each group (section 1)
  - THEN the first object of each group (section 2)
  - THEN back to the second object from each group (section 1)
  - Finally the second object from each group (section 2)
  - e.g.  111 -> 211 -> 311 -> 411 -> 121 -> 221 -> 321 -> 421 -> 112 -> ... -> 122 -> etc.

---

Currently, I am creating an array of values in the order that they should be assigned regardless of the size of the cooling list of CustomObjects.  The objects in the cooling list are unordered and can only be differentiated by parsing for the index in the name. If the array in the example size was actually 6, then you would stop after assigning  221 as per the example above.

```
int count = 0;
Boolean init1 = false;
Boolean init2 = false;
Boolean init3 = false;
Boolean init4 = false;
values = new int[6] {12, 18, 9, 56, 112, 187} //Simplified but normally some code is abstracted and this array comes from another part of my code

do{
  foreach (CustomObject obj in objList) {
    obj.value = -1;
    if(count < values.Length) {
      string name1 = obj.Name.substring(8);
      if (name1.StartWith("1")) {
        if (!init1) {
          obj.Value = values[count++];
          init1 = true;
        }
      }
      if (name1.StartsWith("2")) {
        if (!init2) {
          obj.Value = values[count++];
          init2 = true;
        }
      }
      if (name1.StartsWith("3")) {
        if (!init3) {
          obj.Value = values[count++];
          init3 = true;
        }
      }
      if (name1.StartsWith("4")) {
        if (!init4) {
          obj.Value = values[count++];
          init4 = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if ((count % 4 == 0) && (count > 0) && (count < values.Length)) {
        init1 = false;
        init2 = false;
        init3 = false;
        init4 = false;
      }
      if (count == values.Length) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}while (count < values.Length);
```

Comment: What is your *single* question? We don't do *follow along* type of questions. We are not answering only to serve you but foremost to help future visitors. Just create an [mcve] for one problem you have and need help with.

Comment: @rene How can i create a loop or sequence of conditional statements so that the variables from my array are specifically assigned in the order described by the example: 111 -> 211 -> 311 -> 411 -> 121 -> 221 -> 321 -> 421 -> 112 -> ... -> 122 -> etc.

Comment: @rene My biggest issue is that I have trouble understanding how I can efficiently verify whether or not I should assign the next value from my array each time i progress through the foreach iteration, all while avoiding assigning all of the values at once to the first 6 (for example) elements in the first section. Creating many more flags is clearly not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that Name you use has a sensible structure you can use a `Dictionary` to store an easy key to your CustomObjects and then use an Enumerator on the values to assign them to the `Value` in your custom object:

```
var dict = objList.ToDictionary( k => k.Name, v => v);
dict.Dump();

var values = new int[6] {12, 18, 9, 56, 112, 187};
// enumerator that keeps track where we are
var valuesEnumerator = values.GetEnumerator();

// set all to -1
foreach(var v in dict.Values) v.Value =-1;

const int scale = 4;
//group
for(int g = 1;  g <= scale ; g++)
{
   // section
   for(int s = 1;  s <= scale; s++)
   {
      //item
      for(int i = 1; i <= scale; i++)
      {
            // build a key
            var key = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",i,s,g);
            // check if that key exist
            if (dict.Keys.Contains(key))
            {
                // as long as there numbers in the values array
                if (valuesEnumerator.MoveNext()) 
                {
                    // assign that value
                    dict[key].Value = (int) valuesEnumerator.Current;
                }
            }
      }
   }
}
```

In my test run this returns:

[image: [enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1qIK.png)

Comment: The enumeration to check the current object index is good, but I'm really struggling to replicate a pattern like my example.  To clarify, how can I modify this so that the assignments are as follows:  111=12, 211=18, 311=9, 411=56, 121=112, 221=187.  If there were more values in my list, 321 and 421 would be set next followed by 112...

Comment: Otherwise, it would indeed be easier to follow your pattern and modify how the array is filled (not challenging at all) as long as after 111 is set to 12, 121 = 18, 211=9, 221=56, 311=112, 321=87, etc.  It would be nice if there was some form of final variable set to modify whether this pattern searches for 2 sets of cooling objects or 4 (that being variables in the 100s and 200s distinguished between 300s and 400s) not their corresponding sections.

Comment: Change the order of the key here: `var key = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",i,s,g);`

Comment: So far so good, but as I stated the size of the list could be smaller.  If a group/section was missing an object (for simplicity lets pick 121) yet we still wish to distribute the values equally between the object groups, how would we do so? Currently, the 121 key would not exist and we wish to assign the value to 122 and continue on as with the array as if nothing had happened.  If handled properly, and there was a large array of variables, the next loop through should not overwrite 122 but should advance to 123 while other sections are missing no objects.

Comment: It sounds more like you want to split out that Dictionary further into those groups, sections, items and then apply logic. Or fold all the for loops in an enumerator with your custom logic to progress to the next index. But I have answered your question. It is up to you now.